# How to flip the numbers, add borders to the circle in svg in my case?

Tags: angular, svg

I made a circle like this, like a clock. Here is the [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/j6nD4Bf5lVI8Gu8DSCEx?p=preview).
Some codes from the plnkr:

```
getTransformMatrix() {
  let t;
  const res = [];
  const x = this.items.length - 2;
  for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
    t = -360 / this.items.length * i + (-360 / this.items.length * x);
    res.push('translate(' + 55 + ' ' + 55 + ')' + 'rotate(' + t + ')' + 'translate(' + (-55) + ' ' + (-55) + ')');
   }
 return res;}
```

Now there are problems that I can not solve:

- 1. How to make the numbers smooth and not inverted?
- 2. How to add a Border, that is, split them as in the picture below.
- 3. Why does not the inner circle start right? Can I write a separate function for each circle?

Here's a picture of what I want to see.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same way that you rotate the position of the text around the centre of the circle, you need to rotate the text around its own centre, but in the opposite direction.

I've hacked together a solution in this plunkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/cpkaJwdiVqj6vT2rdteO?p=preview

The changes I made are as follows:

1. The transform for the text needs to be different from the marker lines, so I created a new array `textTransform`.

   ```
   <text *ngFor="let l of items; let i = index" x="53.7" y="105" fill="#F8B133"
         font-size="3" [attr.transform]="textTransform[i]">{{i+1}}</text>

   textTransform = [];

   ngOnInit() {
       this.transform = this.getTransformMatrix();
       this.textTransform = this.getTextTransformMatrix();
   }
   ```
2. And a new function to calculate the transform attributes for the text elements:

   ```
   getTextTransformMatrix() {
       let t;
       const res = [];
       const x = this.items.length - 2;
       for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
         t = -360 / this.items.length * i + (-360 / this.items.length * x);
         res.push('rotate(' + t + ', 55,55) rotate(' + (-t) + ', 54,104)');
       }
       return res;
   }
   ```

   Note that I've used theversion of `rotate()` that takes the coords for the centre of rotation.  It's equivalent to the transform you are doing, but more succinct.

Comment: Thank you. Very helped. And I solved the third problem. Now there is the second problem. What can you advise about second problem?

Comment: There are a couple of ways you could do it. Try just adding a very short arc - one or two pixels in length - at the same place the longer coloured ones start.